Completely forget where one is in Amidah
What does one do if one was davening Amidah on auto-pilot, chas veshalom, and then something happens to interrupt him, and then he realises he has absolutely no idea where in the tefilla he was up to?
Should he start from after the last beracha that he remembers saying (if applicable), or start over, or something else? Please cite sources as I wish to compare and contrast different opinions on this.

@User123 I don't know if you can compare repeating pesukim to repeating brachos.

Seemingly this case should have the same Din as if one is in doubt as to whether he missed an essential part of the Amidah, which in that case he should Daven over again.

@User123 You mean like yaaleh veyavo? But there we assume you forgot. Here it's something like 50/50.

@shmosel, even so one must start over like in OC 64 regarding Krias Shema, and there is no question of a Brachah Levatalah, since he can have in mind that it should be a Nedavah.

Generally any bracha without kavanah should be repeated. However, what you describe is debatable, based on one's standards of kavanah. It also depends on a unit of Amidah. Such an interruption in the first 3 or last 3 brachos may require going back to the start of the unit, while for the middle brachos - to the beginning of the first bracha that one does not remember.
